# Safari test browser doesn't launch with Selenium RC

Tags: selenium

I've been dabbling with Selenium to do some testing on a site and I'm trying to set up RC so I can run tests in multiple browsers. I can run a simple test I put together in both Chrome and Firefox, but when I try to test in Safari, the test window never opens. Things just sort of just sit there, no error message given.

I recorded a video of my test running in Firefox successfully, then in Safari unsuccessfully: http://cl.ly/0G392F2O3X2j0V1S1Q1g

Here's what I see output in the selenium server I have running via the terminal:

```
10:54:10.297 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*safariproxy, http://gdgt.com/, ] on session null
10:54:10.297 INFO - creating new remote session
10:54:10.298 INFO - Allocated session 687ac4cc58364c7d818a054d80a717cb for http://gdgt.com/, launching...
10:54:10.298 INFO - Backing up OS X global network settings...
10:54:10.479 INFO - Modifying OS X global network settings...
10:54:10.855 INFO - Launching Safari to visit 'http://gdgt.com/selenium-server/core/RemoteRunner.html?sessionId=687ac4cc58364c7d818a054d80a717cb&multiWindow=true&baseUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgdgt.com%2F&debugMode=false' via '/var/folders/1k/1kdbzdHKFjuE3YNGCoSGmk+++TI/-Tmp-/customProfileDir687ac4cc58364c7d818a054d80a717cb/redirect_to_go_to_selenium.htm'...
11:07:11.899 WARN - Invalid length: Content-Length=28561 written=22080 for http://storechat.apple.com/hc/6964264/
```

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Selenium Remote Control. From memory, it seems that there was an issue with Safari but I can't find it now.

From the error message in the log it would appear that the connection has been closed before all the content was written.

```
Invalid length: Content-Length=28561 written=22080
```

This means the client closed the connection. In general, it is bad practice to send more than 20,000 characters via a URL. Most browsers do not support this. As a test, you may want to try it again with fewer URL characters (under 20000). If that does not work then:

First, check browser security settings in Safari.
Second, check executable permissions for the Safari executable.

Hope this helps.